# Can someone have the same email address as me?

Tags: gmail

About 10-12 months ago I started receiving emails addressed to someone else.  The first time it happened I figured it was just a typo on the senders part. But then I got more emails from different senders, all addressed to the same person (with a similar name as mine).  I've received emails for her ranging from job interviews, order and shipping confirmations to the most recent one being a legal document that looks rather important. The other person lives in Canada while I live in the US - is it possible that she has the same email address but with @gmail.ca (instead of @gmail.com)?  Since I've received so many of her emails, it makes me wonder if she received any of mine?  I just want the emails to stop and I don't know how to do that aside from sending her a letter (I have her full name and address but the letter would be international and I don't feel like paying to tell someone to change their email address).

Comment: Can you not start by replying to (some of) the emails - especially the legal one - asking what email address they sent it to and explaining that you are not the intended recipient?

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason why it's her who has to change email addresses - you can just as easily change yours.

There is no gmail.ca   all google addresses are .com.

There is yahoo.ca   (well there's definitely yahaoo.ie, so I'm assuming there's also .ca), but I think they make addresses unique across all domains.

It would be courteous of you to reply to each sender, saying

"You have sent this message to me at francis.someone@gmail.com however the contents is not relevant to me.  I suspect it was meant for frances.someone@gmail.com, please check and update your records."